# My Jpanels keep sinking when I go to them

Tags: java

In my program I go from the log in to the main menu,to different areas of the site.

```
    jPanel2.removeAll();
    Items panel = new Items(); 
    jPanel2.add(panel); 
    jPanel2.repaint();
    jPanel2.revalidate();
```

I thought that I found a way to change jpanels so that I can go from one jpanel to another which in the same screen.

The problem with the above code is that each time I change jpanels, the old jpanel isn't gotten rid of, it is staying there, meaning whenever I change jpanels the jpanel slowly gets lower on the page due to it being put underneath the other jpanels that were created before it.

Is there a way to get rid of the jpanels so that when I go to a new jpanel it doesn't slowly lower down the page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use CardLayout to achieve this requirement.

Check this below link.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html

or this SO

[Changing Panels using the Card layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14821952/changing-panels-using-the-card-layout)